Subprocess FileNotFoundError. Subprocess doesn't find file even tho path is correct
When creating a command for subprocess to run it doesnt find the file even though the path to the file is the correct path.
My environment is inside an ssh, with pytorch 2.1, cuda 12.2, python 3.10.12
Here's what I tried with the error messages as well:
command = [
    "python",
    f"{cwd}/mmdetection/tools/train.py",
    f"{project_folder}/{model_config_file}",
    "--auto-scale-lr",
    "--work-dir", f"{project_folder}/train_output"
]

subprocess.run(command)

FileNotFoundError: file "/home/MMDetection/script_headvhelmet_test/retinanet_r50_fpn_1x_coco" does not exist.
It doesn't find the {project_folder}/{model_config_file} path but here's the interesting thing; if I run the command exactly the same except I add ".py" I get this error:
command = [
    "python",
    f"{cwd}/mmdetection/tools/train.py",
    f"{project_folder}/{model_config_file}.py",
    "--auto-scale-lr",
    "--work-dir", f"{project_folder}/train_output"
]

subprocess.run(command)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/MMDetection/script_headvhelmet_test/retinanet_r50_fpn_1x_coco_script_headvhelmet_test.py.py'
So if you noticed the end of the file path was changed from:

retinanet_r50_fpn_1x_coco

to:

retinanet_r50_fpn_1x_coco_script_headvhelmet_test.py.py

The second path is the correct path except the additional ".py" that I added in the command. But without the ".py" in the command it doesnt find the rest of the path, and especially not with a ".py" at the end.
These commands are run back to back so the model_config_file variable never changes
Full traceback of the errors:
Model config before start of training: retinanet_r50_fpn_1x_coco_script_headvhelmet_test.py

Starting training
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/MMDetection/mmdetection/tools/train.py", line 121, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/MMDetection/mmdetection/tools/train.py", line 68, in main
    cfg = Config.fromfile(args.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmengine/config/config.py", line 461, in fromfile
    cfg_dict, cfg_text, env_variables = Config._file2dict(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmengine/config/config.py", line 950, in _file2dict
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmengine/config/config.py", line 892, in _file2dict
    _cfg_dict, _cfg_text, _env_variables = Config._file2dict(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmengine/config/config.py", line 859, in _file2dict
    check_file_exist(filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmengine/utils/path.py", line 23, in check_file_exist
    raise FileNotFoundError(msg_tmpl.format(filename))
FileNotFoundError: file "/home/MMDetection/script_headvhelmet_test/retinanet_r50_fpn_1x_coco" does not exist
First subprocess command run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/MMDetection/mmdetection/tools/train.py", line 121, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/MMDetection/mmdetection/tools/train.py", line 68, in main
    cfg = Config.fromfile(args.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmengine/config/config.py", line 460, in fromfile
    lazy_import is None and not Config._is_lazy_import(filename):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmengine/config/config.py", line 1664, in _is_lazy_import
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/MMDetection/script_headvhelmet_test/retinanet_r50_fpn_1x_coco_script_headvhelmet_test.py.py'

And here is the code in the script:
print(f"Model config before start of training: {model_config_file}")

print("\nStarting training")

# Training start
command = [
    "python",
    f"{cwd}/mmdetection/tools/train.py",
    f"{project_folder}/{model_config_file}",
    "--auto-scale-lr",
    "--work-dir", f"{project_folder}/train_output"
]

subprocess.run(command)

print("First subprocess command run")

command = [
    "python",
    f"{cwd}/mmdetection/tools/train.py",
    f"{project_folder}/{model_config_file}.py",
    "--auto-scale-lr",
    "--work-dir", f"{project_folder}/train_output"
]

subprocess.run(command)


Can you add the output of repr(model_config_file)?

sure here it is: 'retinanet_r50_fpn_1x_coco_script_headvhelmet_test.py'

That change in code can not create the observed change in output. There must be something you did not show us.

Show the full traceback of the errors as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Updated the question at the bottom with full errors shown

Try renaming the project_folder and try again

Thanks but didnt work

you create path with .py.py - maybe you have to skip one .py. And you could copy path from error message and check in system if you can open it - maybe it has some small mistake in name (like double .py.py) which you don't see. You may also use os.listdir(folder) to check what is in folder when you run code,

in code I see some path with mmdetection (with lowecase mmd) but in error I see path with (MMDetection with uppercase MMD) and this can make difference.
